# (Color) without dot in Java

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way in the code below to replace `(Color)` to standard `Color.` (with dot) in getting a color from UserData?

This line

```
rect.setFill((Color) group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData()
```

Wider code fragment based on Oracle doc about ToggleButton

```
tb1.setUserData(Color.LIGHTGREEN);
tb2.setUserData(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
tb3.setUserData(Color.SALMON);

final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(145, 50);

final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){

    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov,
        Toggle toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
            if (new_toggle == null)
                rect.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            else
                rect.setFill(
                    (Color) group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData()
                );
         }
    });
```

Comment: `import static java.awt.Color.*;`

Comment: As Elliott suggests: if you want to turn setUserData(Color.BLACK) to setUserData(BLACK) - just statically import these constants. Beyond that: look into your naming: how can you set *user data* and then pass a color? That method should rather be called `setDisplayColorForUser()` or something alike.

Comment: @GhostCat, are you sure that's the question? Isn't this question about how to avoid casting?

Comment: `(Color)` is a cast. It doesn't use a dot. The fact that you are casting `getUserData()` suggests you maybe returned an `Object` type

Comment: @ModusTollens It is the only Color line that has dots ... if you disagree, I can as well re-open and close-vote for "unclear"

Comment: @GhostCat The question is about casting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Toggle.html#getUserData--

Comment: @GhostCat I guess that unclear is better until OP explains a bit more.

Comment: @cricket_007 That is also just a guess ...

Comment: @GhostCat It's in the question *"based on Oracle doc about ToggleButton"*

Comment: Could you advise me source where I can read more about this statement (Color) - I mean Color with parentheses without dot. Till now i've meet only Color. (with dot) using articles on the internet. So I asked if there is possibility to use standard Color. as a alternative solution to (Color) in this particulatr case believing  that this will help me to undertand how statement (Color) without dot works ;-).

Answer (score 2):

`set` and [`get`-`UserData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Toggle.html#getUserData--) take/return `Object` types.

You need `(Color)` to **cast** the value given by `group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData()`

Unless I misunderstood the question, there doesn't need to be a way to replace that value because those are the properties defined on the `Toggle`... In other words, the value returned is equivalent to the `Color.<VALUE>` defined previously for that Toggle.

Your code can be re-written as this

```
        Color newColor;
        if (new_toggle == null)
            newColor = Color.WHITE;
        else
            newColor = (Color) group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
        rect.setFill(newColor);
```

Or this using a **ternary** expression

```
    rect.setFill(new_toggle == null ? Color.WHITE : (Color) group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData());
```

Comment: Could you advise me source where I can read more about this statement (Color) - I mean Color with parentheses without dot. Till now i've meet only Color. (with dot) using articles on the internet. So I asked if there is possibility to use standard Color. as a alternative solution to (Color) in this particulatr case believing  that this will help me to undertand how statement (Color) without dot works ;-).

Comment: With or without is not the problem. The thing you need to research is called **casting**

Comment: Color with dot is a **static variable** access. The usage `Color c = (Color) variable;` is **casting** the `variable` instance into a `Color` object type